# Gen2 hyper-v vm

Tags: azure, hyper-v

Does anybody know if Hyper-v Gen2 VM's are supported when using ASR Hyper-v to Azure Cloud?

We receive an error "Generation 2 unsupported"

We can see else where on the internet that Gen2 is now supported but we can see how

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They seem to have a workaround (as on March 26 2015) which converts gen-2 to gen-1 during failover and does the reverse during failback.

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-site-recovery-updates-support-for-gen2-vms-networking-enhancements-and-larger-operating-system-drives/

> While Azure works on enabling native support for Generation 2 VMs, we
>   are introducing functionality within ASR that will convert Gen2 VMs to
>   Gen1 during fail over to Azure, and convert them back to Gen2 when you
>   fail back to your on-premises site. This feature has been the top ask
>   from our customers. It will be available to a limited set of users at
>   launch, and it will roll out broadly in the coming weeks.